# Triple indexes in MarkLogic 8

Tags: marklogic

I am writing some POC's for ML8 Java API.
I have enabled triple index for my database in ML8, but I was not able to find any documentation wrt it in the Java API documentation.
So, not sure how to make use of this triple index from Java API or if its a pure database setup thing. 
Please share some info if anyone has..

Answer (score 3):

The MarkLogic REST API ships with two endpoints, `/v1/graphs` and `/v1/graphs/sparql`, which implement the SPARQL protocol.

Use the latter for SPARQL and SPARQL update queries against a REST server.  I've successfully written Java applications when Jena and Sesame, and they work with these endpoints out-of-the-box.

These examples are basically cribbed from Jena and Sesame documenation.  Both projects have excellent docs.

For Sesame, use a SPARQLRepository.

```
Repository rep = new SPARQLRepository(ENDPOINT);
rep.initialize();

RepositoryConnection conn = rep.getConnection();
String queryString = "SELECT ?x ?y WHERE { ?x ?p ?y } ";
TupleQuery tupleQuery = conn.prepareTupleQuery(
        QueryLanguage.SPARQL, queryString);

TupleQueryResult result = tupleQuery.evaluate();
try {
    while (result.hasNext()) { // iterate over the result
        BindingSet bindingSet = result.next();
        Value valueOfX = bindingSet.getValue("x");
        Value valueOfY = bindingSet.getValue("y");
        System.out.println(valueOfX);
        System.out.println(valueOfY);
    }
} finally {
    result.close();
}
```

In Jena, use something like this:

```
String ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:8007/v1/graphs";
HttpAuthenticator authenticator = new SimpleAuthenticator("admin",
            "admin".toCharArray());

// make a model by parsing a file
Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
String turtle = "src/main/resources/data/one.ttl";
model.read(turtle, null);

// configure access to graph protocol
DatasetGraphAccessor markLogicClient = new DatasetGraphAccessorHTTP(
    ENDPOINT, authenticator);
DatasetAdapter datasetAdapter = new DatasetAdapter(markLogicClient);
// add a graph to MarkLogic
datasetAdapter.add(model);


String query = "select ?s ?p ?o where { ?s ?p ?o } limit 1";
QueryExecution queryExec = QueryExecutionFactory
                        .sparqlService(URI, query, authenticator);
ResultSet results = queryExec.execSelect();
logger.debug("Success.  Result: " + results.toString());
for (; results.hasNext();) {
    QuerySolution soln = results.nextSolution();
    Iterator<String> i = soln.varNames();
    for (; i.hasNext();) {
        String n = i.next();
        logger.debug("Name: " + n + " Val: "
            + soln.get(n).toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Java API does not provide much support for the XQuery's 'sem:' function group, you would have to use/write extensions (if one is available) to add the functionality you need. I have asked similar question about loading RDF data a year ago and I think it is a bit relevant to your questions:

[MarkLogic sem: function group in MarkLogic Java API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22459406/marklogic-sem-function-group-in-marklogic-java-api)

There are number of 'workarounds' you can use as you can see in the link above such as REST API calls and mlcp for loading.

Answer (score 0):

Use Java to invoke an [XQuery or JavaScript program which calls the `sem:` API](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/semantics/semantics-api). You could do this by [extending the high-level Java API](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/resourceservices#id_70532) with module invocation, or [use XCC module invocation directly](https://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/xcc/overview-summary.html). If you extend the Java API, you might consider open-sourcing your work for others to use.